# segfault : how to debug

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have a master process that accepts connections and depending on the request, "exec"s a process . The process intermittently crashes with the error :

```
segfault at 11 ip 000000004daa242b sp 00000000ffdc4b18 error 4 in libc-2.5.so[4da32000+153000]
```

How do I go about debugging this? This coming from libc is not helping me much in terms of even getting started on which piece of code is causing this.

Any pointers?

Comment: `Any pointers?` oh the irony...

Comment: What does the stack trace look like?

Comment: @UmNyobe: Now I feel compelled to link to this [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/138/).

Comment: Care to elaborate on *which* process is crashing, and while you're at it, maybe divulge what their general intended tasks are (both parent and launched proc, esp the latter)?

Comment: Note that I cannot attach my debugger (gdb) to the running process. This doesn't happen everytime and it's not reproducible. So when it happens, I have only raised an alert that lets me know that the segfault has occured.

Comment: segfault at 0000000000000011 rip 000000000023a42b rsp 00000000ffd31e78 error 4

Comment: launched process does a client server file transfer.

Comment: run the application with gdb/valgrind all the time till it crashes... then you'll have a starting point...

Comment: On Posix systems, SEGV (presumably signal 11 on your platform) should produce a core dump. You can debug using that, e.g. by looking at the stack trace.

Comment: You're passing junk to libc and it's segfaulting. Learn to use a debugger.

Answer (score 4):

Pointers:

`0x00000001`: The first thing to do is to see if you can work with a debugger or bounds-checker. If that replicates the crash, look for the following (considering the core dump is in libc): corrupted data (callstacks or parameters that have weird values).

`0x00000002`: If that doesn't replicate the crash, add logging to your values that get transmitted into libc functions and see if you catch anything.

`0x00000003`: If logging doesn't give you anything, start disabling parts of your application, combined with artificially increasing load until either the core dump doesn't happen anymore, or it happens every time. One thing to look for: it may be that your core dump is caused only in high stress (which could explain the *intermittent* crashes. See if you can increase load in certain parts of your code by repeating operations (i.e. instead of performing a call that may cause a race condition, run it 100 times one after the other and *see if it does*).

Comment: I am not able to find the core file to start with. Should I be setting anything in /proc/sys/kernel/ ?

Comment: You shoudln't have to. Can you not replace your child process (the one started by your master process) from "<child process>" to  something like "valgrind <child process>"?

Comment: I am afraid I don't have a control over the production env where the code is already deployed.

Comment: So maybe now the question is how to get rid of the core file? I just see this segfault in /var/log/messages, but no further information on where the core file can be found. I checked all the dirs where the binaries are (and the work area from where it is kicked off) and I do'n't see them there.

Comment: Not "get rid of the core file" but meant to ask how to "get hold of the core file". Sorry about that